# Exactly when should I call notifyAppViewWidget?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

My widgets have a listview that is updated along with everything else automatically through "updatePeriodMillis" in the xml.  I have multiple widgets I update inside onUpdate by iterating through the widget ids:

```
for(final int currID: appWidgetIds) {
    final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_my);
    appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(currID, R.id.widgetLV);

    ....network calls, setting the adapter...

    appWidetManager.updateAppWidget(currID, views);
}
```

I've noticed the success of the listview continuinually being updated depends on where I put notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged.  The documentation says it invokes the adapter's onDataSetChanged() callback, where I make a network call that produces the items my listview is filled with.  So why would it depend where inside my loop I call it, as long as it is called for each widget id?  And where is the best place to put it in my loop?